# css-iframe determine location

Tags: css, video, iframe

I just started studying CSS
I'm trying to upload the video to the top of the page but I can't
Would appreciate help

Would appreciate help
`

```
<div class="video">
        <iframe
          width="560"
          height="315"
          src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/YhK8tIfyVwI"
          frameborder="0"
          allow=" autoplay;  picture-in-picture"
          allowfullscreen
        ></iframe>
      </div>
```

`